# How to plot a equation like ay + bx + c = 0 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, equation

I've already searched it here but I couldn't found it the way I was looking for.

I kind managed to do it using Symbolic Math but I don't understand it quite well. For exemple, after doing that

> > syms y x
> >     ezplot(-y + x + 1 == 0)

i get a nice graph, but can I use this expression later to calculate its value? like, first I want to plot -y + x + 1 == 0 and at another moment I want to solve f(3) for exemple, where f(x) = x + 1 (same equation).

I know I can write a function to do that, but as a function I don't know how to plot it. In the other way, I know how to plot using symbolic math, but I don't know how to calculate it after.

I'm writing a PLA algorithm and them I need to generate the 'a', 'b' 'c' for the equation, that why I need to know how to plot and solve in a "systematic code" way, and not typing one by one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you gave us is a straight line, so a polynomial. The coefficients are y= -b/a*x -c/a.

```
% ay + bx + c = 0 reads y = -b/a*x - c/a*1
a = -1; 
b = 1;
c = 1;
p = [-b/a, -c/a];   % polynomial representing your equation

% plot like this
x = linspace(-2,2, 50);
figure
plot(x, polyval(p,x)) % evaluate polynomial p at the positions x

% find the solution
roots(p) # -1
```

If you need or want to use ezplot, you can put the polyval-expression in an inline function and you can call ezplot with that handle:

```
f = @(x) polyval(p, x); % the function
ezplot(f)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just define `f` to be a *function* of the symbolic variable `x`:

```
>> syms x
>> f = x+1;
```

Then you can use `f` as the input to [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/ezplot.html):

```
>> ezplot(f)
```

which produces the graph

[image]

On the other hand, to solve the equation *f*(*x*)=0 use [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/solve.html) as follows:

```
>> solve(f)
ans =
-1
```

---

`ezplot` and `solve` can be used with *string* inputs as well, but the string has to be different in either case. To plot the graph:

```
>> ezplot('x+1');
```

To solve the equation:

```
>> solve('x+1=0')
ans =
-1
```